# Automatic setting of bar colours in a stacked bar chart using DataPlotly

Tags: qgis, chart, dataplotly

I'm building a bar chart from attribute table using DataPlotly.
I have set the colour scale for bars setting this expression:

```
case
when "field" = 'A'
then '#06e79e'
when "field" = 'B'
then '#e70606'
when "field" = 'C'
then '#9c6ffc'
when "field" = 'D'
then '#6fddfc'
when "field" = 'E'
then '#e3fc6f'
else "field"
end
```

in `marker color` > edit
[image]

but I wonder if it is possible to set an automatic colour scale depending on existent values. This is particularly important when dealing with hundreds of different attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Data Defined` button and set the `get_symbol_color` expression from the DataPlotly category:

[image]

This will automatically set the plot item color to the map feature color